# Refer to array based on string output

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm learning Swift as I go here, so apologies if this is a silly question.

I'm looking to use the output of one function (String) to determine an input into a different function (Array).

The first function output (String) is then combined with another String to form the name of an already defined Array, which i'd like to use as input to second function. However, despite having the same name, the String is not seen as an array.

I've skipped some of the code, but relevant section below.

```
// Defined array
let rushProb = [0,11,19,64,78,89,96,98,99,100]

// Define probability and outcome function - PlayType
func findPlay(prob: [Int], outcome: [String]) -> String {
    if let index = prob.firstIndex(where: { $0 > Int.random(in: 1...100) }) {
        return outcome[index]
    }
    else {
        return "na"
    }
}

// This is successfully output as "rush"
let playSel = findPlay(prob: scen1Prob, outcome: scenPlay)

// This then creates "rushProb"
let playSelProb = playSel+"Prob"

// I want this to ultimately be findYards(prob: rushProb)
findYards(prob: playSelProb)
```

Comment: variable names don't have a meaning at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use a dictionary where the key replaces your array name, and the value is the array.  Then, you'd use the name you create to look up the array value in the dictionary:

```
let arrays = ["rushProb": [0,11,19,64,78,89,96,98,99,100],
              "fooProb" : [0,15,29,44,68,78,86,92,94,100]]

// This is successfully output as "rush"
let playSel = findPlay(prob: scen1Prob, outcome: scenPlay)

// This then creates "rushProb"
let playSelProb = playSel+"Prob"

// look up the array that corresponds to "rushProb"
if let array = arrays[playSelProb] {
    findYards(prob: array)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to 100K! Well deserved

Comment: Thanks @matt!  That means a lot coming from you!